# Find out if a cell in the form is selected or not selected

Tags: python, opencv

Good afternoon. My task is to take a questionnaire and write the selected options into the database, according to the type true or false. With the help of Microsoft Recognize, I get the desired table and then with the help of cm2, I make a crop of the image to understand whether it is true or false.

```
imagePage = cv2.imread(image.path)
x = int(coordinates[0])
y = int(coordinates[1])
w = int(coordinates[2])
h = int(coordinates[3])
imageCell = imagePage[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.rectangle(imagePage, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

Table with selected cells:

[image: Table with selected cells]

Next, the idea was to check by the presence of black pixels. If there are many of them, then the item has been selected and it is true. Unfortunately, this does not work, because the border of the lines, which are also considered black pixels, fall.

```
def countBlackPixels(imageCell):
lowerBlack = np.array([0, 0, 0], np.uint8)
blackRange = cv2.inRange(imageCell, lowerBlack, lowerBlack)
blackPixels = cv2.countNonZero(blackRange)
return blackPixels
```

For example, one cell with X shows 258 black pixels, the second cell with X shows 98.

Are there any ways to read in the questionnaire the answers to the cells that are presented in the format: X, V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between two cells in terms of number of black cells felt like way too high.

This is possibly be the result of selection of borders in a given cell.

I wonder what is the result of

```
def countBlackPixels(imageCell):
```

for an empty cell.

Maybe we can set a threshold from this value to decide whether or not a cell is checked.

If that does not look promising, maybe we can rewrite the countBlackPixels() to look for the center area of the cell specifically.

Something like this:

[image: Something like this]

Waiting to hear from you!

Comment: For my example, below is the number of black pixels for each cell (in order)

Black pixels: 518
Black pixels: 581
Black pixels: 663
Black pixels: 340
Black pixels: 172
Black pixels: 234
Black pixels: 292
Black pixels: 99


It's a good idea to use a central area. If I understood correctly, for this I need to take the border of the original cell and uniformly reduce all parameters by n quantity?

Comment: Thank you for the results. It seems like the border effects them a lot. Exactly! You can write a function, just like the one you did; but this time, change the "blackRange" to a **smaller area** that is again a rectangle, with the same center. (To do this, you can multipy the height and the weight of the rectangle with a constant "n", something like 0.7)

Comment: Yes, thank so much for help. Unfortunately, I can't give you a rating, because I have a small reputation. But thank you very much

Comment: @beg2016 Even with small reputation you can accept the answer, please, if this is the solution of your issue!